# Is there a way to prove the following $AX=Y$ has a solution iff $(A|Y)X' = 0$ has a solution?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> $AX=Y$ has a solution iff $(A|Y)X' = 0$ has a solution

Assume that $AX = Y$ has a solution where $A$ is a $n \times m$ matrix. Let $X = (x_1,\cdots,x_n)$ be the solution to $AX = Y$ then $(x_1,\cdots,x_n,-1)$ is a solution to $(A|Y)X' = 0 $. I am not sure how to prove the converse.

Also if this holds then we can conclude that $(A|Y)X' = 0$ has one solution then it means that it has infinitely many solutions then from here can we conclude that $AX = Y$ has infinitely many solutions? What is the geometric significance to this?